# Excel PowerQuery - Dynamically Change Source from Cell Value

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerquery, ms-access-2016

For a project, I'm trying to query an Access database from Excel using PowerQuery. The path to the file will be set in a cell on the sheet and each user will change it as necessary.

I've tried the following code below, as well as endless examples from Google, however it always results in the error: `DataFormat.Error: The supplied file path must be a valid absolute path. Details: ‪D:\Downloads\Database.accdb`

```
let
//FilePath = Text.From(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="File"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]),

//Name='File' refers to a named cell called File with the value of 'D:\Downloads\'
Path = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="File"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
FilePath = Text.From("" & Path & ""),
Source = Access.Database(File.Contents(FilePath & "Database.accdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
_Stores = Source{[Schema="",Item="Stores"]}[Data],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(_Stores,{{"Open Time", type time}, {"Close Time", type time}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"State", "Routes(City)", "Routes(City) 2"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"City", "Store"}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "CurTime", each DateTime.LocalNow()),
#"Inserted Time" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Time", each DateTime.Time([CurTime]), type time),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Time",{"CurTime"}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Hours Until Close", each Duration.Hours(Duration.From(DateTime.Time([Close Time])-DateTime.Time(DateTime.LocalNow())))),
#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Time"})                                
in
#"Removed Columns2"
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: What does the `Source` statement look like when you create a query to the db directly? What do the variables `Path` and `FilePath` resolve to when you step through the steps? Any inconsistencies is where you should start troubleshooting. Maybe a missing backslash  character between FilePath and the database name?

Comment: @teylyn Based on the error, the resulting path is correct. The full path should be `D:\Downloads\Database.accdb`.  The original Source statement is `Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("D:\Downloads\Database.accdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])`

Comment: I am new to PowerQuery. Exactly where is the posted code located?

Comment: @June7 `Home / Advanced Editor`

Comment: I tried refencing MyPC Downloads as `C:\Downloads` and just `Downloads` and those generate the error. However `C:\Users\Owner\Downloads` does work. The comment doesn't like end \ so I dropped here but actually is in code.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the error. This code works just fine for me.

```
let
    Path = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="File"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
    FilePath = Text.From("" & Path & ""),
    Source = Access.Database(File.Contents(FilePath & "Database.accdb"))
//   Source = Access.Database(File.Contents("C:\demo\Database.accdb"), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])
in
    Source
```

Check for spelling and missing characters in your variables.